# Android Sample - SlidingTabsColors - How to select a perticular tab

Tags: android, colors, tabs

I am creating my first ever android app. For this I have followed this example to create a very nice [sliding tabbed layout](http://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsColors/project.html).

It's very good, but there is a small problem.

I have created about 5 tabs, each supported by 5 different fragments containing their own controls. When I exit the app with back button and start it again, all my controls on each page retain their state (using my Singleton parameters class). But on each reopening, the app starts with first tab selected. Even if I was working on 5th tab and existed from there, the app shows the first tab only.

I could keep the tab index in my singleton class, but how do I set it such that the app always opens with last open tab using something like `setSelectedTab(tabIndex)`? And where should I call this method?

Thanks a ton in advance for the help.